# Find locations within distance of multiple locations

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to run a query that will find locations with a given distance of any of the given locations. This is for a search result where users can select multiple locations to look around.

My current approach is to use `ST_ClosestPoint` and pass in an array of `ST_Point` generated in PHP. Then I pass that string into `ST_Collect`.

```php
$points = $locations->map(function ($location) {
    return sprintf('ST_Point(%s, %s)', $location->longitude, $location->latitude);
})->implode(', ');
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM listing_locations
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    coordinate,
    ST_ClosestPoint(coordinate, ST_Collect(Array[%s]),
    1000, 
FALSE)
```

However, this doesn't work because it looks like `ST_ClosestPoint` doesn't like these mixed arguments:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function st_closestpoint(geometry, geography) does not exist
```

I have a `gist(coordinate::geography)` index on `listing_locations` which seems like it would be useful to use.

What am I missing - is there a better way to do this, or is this a bad approach? Should I be performing the query each time with a different location?

Comment: You could also create a second index using geometry and then cast to geometry which will use that index when the query is fired. An example can be found here towards the end of the post http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2021/05/indexes-and-queries.html

Comment: `\df ST_Collect` says st_collect return geometry type. can you just write the value in query. and directly query it in psql?

Comment: @TimothyDalton if I try to run the query having cast the coordinate to a geometry (`ST_DWithin (coordinate, ST_ClosestPoint (coordinate::geometry, ST_Collect (ARRAY [ST_Point(-81.70361, 28.62167), ST_Point(-108.6571, 48.8542)])), 25000, FALSE)`) I still get an error: `Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  LWGEOM_closestpoint: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Point, 4326) != (MultiPoint, 0)`

Comment: @Dwight I found out this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68711/postgis-geometry-query-returns-error-operation-on-mixed-srid-geometries-only

Comment: `select ST_SRID(ST_Point(-81.70361, 28.62167));` will return 0. means your coordinate column already have srid.

Comment: So you should try `(ST_DWithin (coordinate, ST_ClosestPoint (coordinate::geometry,
ST_Collect (ARRAY [ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-81.70361, 28.62167),4326),
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-108.6571, 48.8542),4326)]), 25000, FALSE))`

Comment: I have tried that now - however now it appears to return all records. Even if I set the distance to zero it still returns records: `SELECT * FROM listing_locations WHERE ST_DWithin (
  coordinate, 
  ST_ClosestPoint (coordinate::geometry, ST_Collect (ARRAY [
   ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-81.70361, 28.62167), 4326)
  ])), 2500, FALSE)`

Comment: @Dwight https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b438a93e7d395704927d970c37e70189 support postgis. can You share some sample column coordinate data?

Comment: Here you go - no matter how I adjust the distance the final query returns all 100 rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=db7874f93ec6229d28464fad00bd5ee2

Comment: @Dwight is the 100 in ST_DWithin supposed to be degrees?

Comment: No - my intention was to be searching with metres. So I see now that perhaps I need both inputs to be `geography` then? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Comment: @Dwight perhaps this? 
`WITH j (point) AS (
  VALUES 
 (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-81.70361, 28.62167), 4326)::geography),
 (...)
)
SELECT * FROM listing_locations
JOIN j ON ST_DWithin(j.point,coordinate,100,false)`.. that is, if you can pass the given points in the `VALUES` inside the CTE

Comment: @Dwight for instance, within a radius of 13km of two given points: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c42f8b98cca083d8ad803433af93458

Comment: @Dwight or even with `ST_Collect`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ee41aee82eab130b052e08e370ad5d3c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things simpler put the `ST_Collect` in a subquery or CTE, and in the outer query use `ST_DWithin` with the newly created MultiPoint, the column `coordinate` and a given distance, e.g.

```sql
WITH j (points) AS (
  SELECT 
   ST_Collect( 
    (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-81.70361, 28.62167), 4326)),
    (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-81.70365, 28.62169), 4326))
   )::geography
)
SELECT *, ST_Distance(j.points,coordinate) AS distance
FROM listing_locations
JOIN j ON ST_DWithin(j.points,coordinate,100,false);
```

Or put it in a spatial join (imho less readable)

```sql
SELECT *, ST_Distance(j.points,coordinate) AS distance
FROM listing_locations
JOIN (SELECT
       ST_Collect( 
        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-81.70361, 28.62167), 4326)),
        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-81.70365, 28.62169), 4326))
       )::geography) j (points)
       ON ST_DWithin(j.points,coordinate,100,false);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eff1848c262ed043c810e3759155c866)

Comment: Perfect - thank you for taking the time to dig down and explain this. I now have a better understanding of PostGIS and the data types, and I learnt about the `WITH` function.